# Symfony2 and Doctrine APC Cache

Tags: symfony, doctrine, apc

i have read the documentation of symfony2 in relation to the performance and I have realized the following steps.

1. Install APC 'php-apc' on my webserver and restart my webserver
2. Modify my doctrine configuration

   ```
   doctrine:

   dbal:

       driver:   "%database_driver%"
       host:     "%database_host%"
       port:     "%database_port%"
       dbname:   "%database_name%"
       user:     "%database_user%"
       password: "%database_password%"
       charset:  UTF8

      orm:

       auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
       auto_mapping: true
       metadata_cache_driver: apc
       result_cache_driver: apc
       query_cache_driver: apc
   ```

Now if i call a action to retrieve all users from database i see in the information bar at the bottom that doctrine execute every time 114 queries. Why the queries not cached?

My action look like this:

```
$users = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppUserBundle:User')->findAll();
return $this->render('AppUserBundle:User:index.html.twig', array('users' => $users));
```

Comment: which version of doctrine are you using?

Comment: I'm not at office now, but i mean doctrine 2.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doctrine doesn't cache query results by default. You have to explicitly point that you want to cache query using `useResultCache` method. For example, if you'd like to cache getting all users, write your own method in User repository class:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class UserRepository extends EntityRepository
{

    public function fetchAll()
    {
        $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')->getQuery();

        return $query->useResultCache(true)->getResult();
    }
}
```

The method may take additional arguments:

```
public function useResultCache($bool, $lifetime = null, $resultCacheId = null)
```

- $bool - set to `true` if you want to cache query result
- $lifetime - TTL of cached result in seconds
- $resultCacheId - you can pass your own id, in case of `null` Doctrine will handle that

Comment: Many thanks this work now :) I think i must create an base repository with some "find / fetch" functions and than extend my base repository. So i can use it for every repository.